# How to use @PostConstruct to create timers in a stateless bean EJB3?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, weblogic, weblogic11g

I want to create a timer EJB3 when a stateless bean is created in the pool.
But if I use `@PostConstruct` I get the exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010193]Illegal call to EJBContext method. The bean is in "null" state. It cannot perform 'getting the Timer Service' action(s). Refer to the EJB specification for more details.`

If container calls @PostConstruct, the bean ins't null. So, why I get this exception?

---

**CLASS**

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestLocal {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startTimer() {
        if (timerService.getTimers().size() == 0) {
            timerService.createTimer(1 * 1000, 1 * 1000, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {        
    }

}
```

---

**INTERFACE**

```
@Local
public interface TesteLocal {

    void test();

}
```

---

**SERVLET**

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private TestLocal test;

    protected void doGet(....) throws .... {
        test.test();
    }
}
```

---

**DETAILS**

I'm using weblogic server 11g.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think that the bean class must implement `javax.ejb.TimedObject` or have a method annotated with `@Timeout` to use EJB timers. Example:

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestLocal {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startTimer() {
        if (timerService.getTimers().size() == 0) {
            timerService.createTimer(1 * 1000, 1 * 1000, null);
        }
    }

    @Timeout
    @TransactionAttribute(value=REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void timeoutCallback(Timer timer) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Does WebLogic still complain with the above code?

PS: In any case, the error you currently get is very poorly reported, you should probably open a case.

Comment: I follow your example, making 2 changes:  a) TestLocal has a method to be implemented by TestBean (without this, weblogic can't deploy) b) a create a servlet that calls the EJB. The error still happens.

Comment: @Topera I was really not sure (I'm not even sure that what I suggested is mandatory with EJB 3.0). I may be wrong but this looks like a bug. I suggest contacting the support

Comment: Indeed, this code won't run, as Mike said. Timers can't be accessed or started from a @Postconstruct method.

Answer (score 7):

You can NOT use a @PostConstruct to create a timer in a stateless bean EJB 3. See this blog [How to use EJB 3 timer in a weblogic 10 cluster environment](http://shaoxiongyang.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-ejb-3-timer-in-weblogic-10.html) for the explanation. Even the blog was talking about weblogic, but the explanation should apply to other app servers also.

Comment: Yes, same issue occurs in JBoss

Comment: Although this explains why it is not possible, it does not give an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Container will not allow for timerService in method annotated with @PostConstruct of Stateless Session Bean. If you want to use timerService in method annotated with @PostConstruct the go for Singleton session bean(@Singleton).